# Why this code snippet can't compile whereas `print(square(3,0))` is ok?

Tags: for-loop, lua

Why this code snippet can't compile whereas `print(square(3,0))` is ok?

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)

   if currentNumber<iteratorMaxCount
   then
      currentNumber = currentNumber+1
      return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber
   end
    
end

print(square(3,0))

for i,n in square(3,0)
do 
   print(i,n)
end
```

The compiler complains that:

```
> $lua main.lua 1   1 lua: main.lua:13: attempt to call a number value
> stack traceback:  main.lua:13: in main chunk  [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Replace `for i,n in square(3,0)` with `for i,n in square,3,0`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Could you answer this question? Otherwise it will stay formally unanswered for ever.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin - I don't have an answer.  My comment is just a hint.  An answer should include explanation on how generic for-loop in Lua works.  Feel free to write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`for i,n in square(3,0)` is equivalent to `for i,n in 1,1` and this means you are attempting to call `1` which is not a function and results in your error `attempt to call a number value`.

The first value in the expression list after `in` in the for loop definition needs to be a function, such as `pairs` or `ipairs` which are used when working with tables or arrays. If you're using some custom iterator, like `square` in your code, you want to create a function that defines the iterator storing limits as up values and returns an anonymous function, A function that does this is called an iterator factory.

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)
    return function()
        if currentNumber<iteratorMaxCount then
            currentNumber = currentNumber+1
            return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber
        end
    end
end

print(square(3,0)())
print(square(3,0))

for i,n in square(3,0) do 
    print(i,n)
end
```

---

Alternatively you can pass initial state to the function by defining 2 more values in the for loop expression list, the invariant state and a control variable.

```
for i,n in square,3,0 do 
    print(i,n)
end
```

Suggested Reading:

> [Programming in Lua: 7.2 – The Semantics of the Generic for](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.2.html)

Related Topics:

> [Programming in Lua: 4.3.5 – Generic for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html)

> [Programming in Lua: 7.1 – Iterators and Closures](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html)

> [Programming in Lua: 7.3 – Stateless Iterators](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html)